# Small motor seized

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, repair, single-phase

Alright I'm trying to get my pellet grill up and running prior to Thanksgiving and I seem to have a seized motor.

The past few days I was working on clearing a pellet clog in the middle of the auger shift. After many struggles and disassembling the housing to try to force the drive shift I managed to burn out the clog and the unit started to run albeit weakly and backwards likely due to me putting the motor on backwards.

I went to try to reverse the direction and now the motor is seized. I have removed the motor from the gearbox to ensure no major gear issues and tested it independently and it just hums.

I have cleaned the motor and the housing without luck. I can insert the motor and drive into the housing and it spins freely when not under load. Under load and in either direction it hums and resists rotation in either direction.

Pictures are attached.[image]

Comment: that is not a DC motor ... `seized` means that bearings are so damaged that the rotor will not turn ... you are describing something else

Comment: did you install the stator backward? (the part in the picture)

Comment: When you say it turns freely under no load -- are you spinning the motor's rotor (the round thing that goes into the round hole in that frame)?  Or are you spinning something else, like the output shaft of the gearbox.  Those motors are dead simple, and the electrical part usually Does Not Die -- it's usually some mechanical part that wears out or corrodes.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the frame of a typical consumer shaded-pole induction motor -- the thing that goes into the round hole is the motor's rotor.

There's only three things that can be broken: the frame (the part pictured), the rotor, or the mechanical assembly (bearings and whatnot).  If it spins freely with no load, then it's not the bearings.  If turning it on doesn't pull the rotor in some direction that it rubs and won't turn, then it's not the whatnot.

I'm finding it really hard to believe that you could have burnt the thing out -- usually when those go, it's the bearings.  Just about any ceiling fan will have an assembly like the one you picture (and a rotor); if you get desperate you could try a different frame in place of the one you have.  Ditto the rotor, if you can find one that fits mechanically.